# 'Error: Read-only file system', even with root privileges in Bash shell

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, 17.10

I have Ubuntu 17.10 with gnome installed on it. Something I did (removing a folder from `/usr/share/gnome-shell`) made me unable to use GNOME. So, I booted into recovery mode with root privileges. I made a backup of that folder before I deleted it, so I thought it would be as easy as `cp -r <backup> <destination>`.

Sadly, even with root privileges, it told me that it was unable to copy since `/usr/share/gnome-shell/` is read-only. What do I do? Have no access to GNOME at all, and I am doing this in the Ubuntu bash recovery mode, so I can only do terminal commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, filesystems are mounted with the readonly (`ro`) option when in recovery mode. You will need to re-mount `/` in read-write (`rw`) mode:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```